# LightBox conflits with jquery.animate-enhanced

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, lightbox

I got two plugins added to my webpage. The [LightBox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) and [animate-enhanced](http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/)

They are both working fine. The problem is that when I click images to displays LightBox, it display the modal dialog fine, but the `lightboxOverlay` gets `opacity:1` instead of `opacity:0.8` as it should be. This happens because of the second plugin that for some reason is affecting `lightboxOverlay`.

How can I solve this issue? Can I somehow "tell" for example `<div class="lightbox">` to ignore the `animate-enhanced` plugin script?

In the picture attached you can see that it has `opacity:1` overriding `opacity:0.8` as it should be.

I don't display code because I don't think it's relevant due being a overriding scripts issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. Not the best way to do it but I forced to `opacity:0.8`.